# How can I automatically add text from a webpage to a "Twitter Share" button?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter, hyperlink

I have a random quote generator for which I'd like to have an option for the user to tweet the current quote being displayed. I have already added a blank hyper link tag in HTML and edited it using this code in jQuery, with currentQuote being the variable which holds the current display quote:

```
$('.twitter-share-button').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + currentQuote);
```

This pulls up a twitter submit box, but does not automatically add my quote inside.

Here's the project:
http://codepen.io/biancalelei/pen/vLeJVd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable scope of your code was wrong.
You need to define currentQuote outside your function to get it working!

So change

```
var currentQuote = quotes[randomNumber];
```

to

```
currentQuote = quotes[randomNumber];
```

and add the decleration of the variable at the beginning of your code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentQuote = '';
.....
```

also change the click section to update the value everytime a new quote is generated

```
$('.new').on('click', function(){
  newQuote();
  $('.twitter-share-button').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + currentQuote);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oboYLo

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! But this only adds the quote that was first generated on the page. I'm looking to post each individual quote that's currently being shown.